# Vespa multi vector indexing throwing error

Tags: vespa

I tried to work with the **Multi Vector Indexing** feature of Vespa.
I cloned the multi-vector-indexing repository: https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/tree/master/multi-vector-indexing

When I tried to deploy the application package I was getting the following error:

```
Uploading application package ... failed
Error: invalid application package (400 Bad Request)
Invalid application package:
Error loading default.default:
For schema 'wiki', field 'paragraph_embeddings':
A tensor of type 'tensor<float>(p{},x[384])' does not support having an 'index'. 
Currently, only tensors with 1 indexed dimension supports that.
```

Installed vespa version: `Vespa CLI version 8.153.19 compiled with go1.20.3 on darwin/arm64`

Docker total memory: `Total Memory: 7.668GiB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a too old version of Vespa.

Note that you are posting the version of the Vespa command line client, not Vespa itself above.